# Make SAPI TTS speak string variables

Tags: c++, text-to-speech, sapi

So, I have a program where I use SAPI like this:

```
ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
{
    return FALSE;
}

HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void     **)&pVoice);
if( SUCCEEDED( hr ) )
{
    hr = pVoice->Speak(L"I can talk!", SPF_IS_XML, NULL);
}
```

But I want to declare a variable and then have the sapi say them. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Variables are right near the beginning in any C++ tutorial. It's wise to get to learn the language at least a little bit.

Comment: I'm pretty familiar with C++, but SAPI is a bit more complicated than anything I've dealt with before.

Comment: Nothing changes about using variables with SAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `std::wstring`. Assuming you want the user to input what to say (barring a textbox and a button):

```
std::cout << "Enter lines of text to speak:\n";
for (std::wstring text; std::wcin >> text;) {
    if (FAILED(hr = pVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), SPF_IS_XML, NULL))) {
        std::cout << "Sorry, the text could not be spoken. The error code is " << hr << '\n';
    }
}
```